# Empty stdin when piping tool

Tags: c++, unix, pipe

I've spent the whole day looking at threads on how to make my tool "mybin" capable of being put in a pipeline.

Imagine that file.txt is a list of numbers, one per line. I want to be able to do

```
cat file.txt | mybin
```

If I read directly from standard input this will fail, although the following will succeed

```
mybin < file.txt
```

So I looked into pipes, and there's a lot of sources repeating the same info of creating a process, forking and creating pipes for the parent and child to communicate. But nothing useful when the pipe comes from an external source.

My problem, I think, is how to get the pipe I initialize internally to be connected to the pipe after "cat file.txt".

To give you an idea of what I am currently doing:

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
dup2(STDIN_FILENO, fd[0]);
boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_source> is(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor_source(fd[0], boost::iostreams::never_close_handle));
```

At this point I pretty much have a usual C++ stream and proceed to use `std::getline` in a loop.

When using the "<" version of the command, `seekg(0, is.end)` returns a positive value, but when I use the "|" version the command, `seekg(0, is.end) == -1`.
Which is why I think my problem is that I need something else than `STDIN_FILENO` to be copied onto my input pipe.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you need `pipe(fd);` if both of your shell execution samples already redirect to `stdin` for you?

Comment: I want to use my tool like this: `cat file.txt | mybin`. stdin is empty when I use it this way, so I thought "|" is a pipe, let's look into `pipe` objects.

Comment: Of course my code isn't doring anything really different as long as I use STDIN_FILENO and copy it onto the pipe, what I am asking for is what I should use instead of STDIN_FILENO.